# Is it ok to wear trousers if needed at work?

Tags: halacha, tznius-modesty

If a woman is working in a hospital and the hospital has a dress code that includes trousers and there are no skirts available - Is it ok for the lady to wear trousers? Are there any sources that discuss this or a similar scenario.

Comment: This question would be more compelling if it included some notion of why it may be a problem for a woman to wear trousers in the first place.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Anne and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: In the past men wore robes reminiscent of dresses/skirts, men on some countries even wore heels at one time. Whether clothing is considered ‘masculine’ or ‘feminine’ is partly time-bound. That said, these days we have women’s pants and men’s pants that often differ in style, form, color etc. which makes a clear distinction between the two. The same applies to other clothing or uniforms for example; distinguish by different combinations for men and women.

Comment: Which issue are you coming from lo tilbash,or tznius